# Do WinAPI Slim Reader/Writer (SRW) Locks use memory barriers?

Tags: winapi

The WinAPI Docu says:

"The following synchronization functions use the appropriate barriers to ensure memory ordering:

- Functions that enter or leave critical sections
- Functions that signal synchronization objects
- Wait functions
- Interlocked functions"

[Synchonization Docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/synchronization-and-multiprocessor-issues)

Now the question is: Do WinAPI Slim Reader/Writer (SRW) Locks also use memory barriers?

[SRW Locks Docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks)

Note: WinAPI SRW Locks are neither critical sections nor synchronization objects.

Comment: yes. also use. internal this api use Interlocked functions

Comment: They are useless anyway (no recursive locks, no upgrade).

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Isn't that what makes them "slim"?

Comment: I assume you interest in read and write operation order when you are talking about [MemoryBarrier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/nf-winnt-memorybarrier). And un-document API or feature are not suggested to use.

Comment: It is very likely that winapi SRW locks use the same memory barriers as winapi critical sections.
As long as it is not verified, the SRW locks can't be used in "production code".
Inside of a lock-unlock pair the memory barriers are necessary to safely access shared data. lock: read barrier, unlock: write barrier